# ActionScript 3 Refactoring image loaders

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have the following code in ActionScript3 for loading images:

```
// Create the image areas
    var imageArea1 = new imageArea();
    var imageArea2 = new imageArea();
    var imageArea3 = new imageArea();
    var imageArea4 = new imageArea();
    var imageArea5 = new imageArea();

    var image1;
    var image2; 
    var image3; 
    var image4; 
    var image5;

    addChild(imageArea1);
    addChild(imageArea2);
    addChild(imageArea3);
    addChild(imageArea4);
    addChild(imageArea5);

    // Image1
    // function to load images to the page
    function loadImage1(url:String):void {
        image1 = new Loader();
        image1.load(new URLRequest(url));
        image1.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded1); 
    }

    //Callback event after image has been loaded.
    function imageLoaded1(e:Event):void { 
        // Load Image 
        imageArea1.addChild(image1);//display the photo
        //trace ('width:'+image1.width,' height:'+image1.height);
        image1.y = (stageHeight-image1.height);
        //trace(image1.y);
        var otherindex = getChildIndex(myBackground)
        setChildIndex(imageArea1,otherindex + 1);
    }
```

From the looks of it, I would have to copy and paste loadImage1 and imageLoaded1 functions for each image. I would ideally like to somehow pass in params to the .addEventListener function.

How can I refactor this so that I don't have to copy and paste the functions for each image, it seems repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way will be to add the imageX as a parameter:

```
function loadImage(url:String, imageObj:Object):void {
    imageObj = new Loader();
    imageObj.load(new URLRequest(url));
    imageObj.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded1); 
}
```

Will that be good for you? I hope it will :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I haven't tested it, but it should work if you can get it to compile -- don't forget the proper imports `;-)` ):

```
var imageURLs:Array = ['blah.png', 'blah2.png', 'foo.png'];
var imageLoaders:Array = new Array();
var imageAreas:Array = new Array();

for each (var url:String in imageURLs) {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
    loader.load(new URLRequest(url));

    imageLoaders.push(loader);

    var theImageArea:imageArea = new imageArea();
    addChild(theImageArea);
    imageAreas.push(theImageArea);
}

function imageLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    var loader:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);

    var index:int = imageLoaders.indexOf(loader);
    imageAreas[index].addChild(loader);

    loader.y = (stageHeight - loader.height);

    var otherChildIndex:int = getChildIndex(myBackground);
    setChildIndex(imageAreas[index], otherChildIndex + 1);
}
```